# Array List referecing in recursive calls

Tags: java, recursion, reference, copy

Given the code bellow, I facing the following problem: I have this ArrayList that is supposed to store my solutions in it. On the first if condition, if I print there, It prints the solutions correctly. However, outside this function, it just print a single false matrix. In that in mind I suppose I having problems with referencing the object or something like that.

The solutions ArrayList was declared as an attribute of the class, I was hoping that, when the recursive backtracking found a solution and added to the ArrayList, it would update the attribute and I would be able to use it trough the whole class.

I was reading about the .clone() method, and thinking about passing a copy of solutions on each recursive call, but I not sure exactly how it would work..

```
public void recursiveBacktracking (ArrayList<boolean[][]> solutions, int x, int y, boolean visited[][]) {
    
    visited[x][y] = true;

    if (x == eRow && y == eCol) {
        solutions.add(visited);
        // If I print here..

    }

    if (isValidCell(x, y)) {
        // go down (x, y)
        if (x + 1 < map.getRow() && !visited[x + 1][y]) {
            recursiveBacktracking(solutions, x + 1, y, visited);
        }

        // go up (x, y)
        if (x - 1 >= 0 && !visited[x - 1][y]) {
            recursiveBacktracking(solutions, x - 1, y, visited);
        }

        // go right (x, y)
        if (y + 1 < map.getCol() && !visited[x][y + 1]) {
            recursiveBacktracking(solutions, x, y + 1, visited);

        }

        // go left (x, y)
        if (y - 1 >= 0 && !visited[x][y - 1]) {
            recursiveBacktracking(solutions, x, y - 1, visited);
        }
    }

    // backtrack from current cell and remove it from current path
    visited[x][y] = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

does changing

```
solutions.add(visited);
```

to

```
solutions.add(visited.clone());
```

is working for you?

Note that:

- As you are working with references, the last line in your function forces every cell of the solutions matrix to be false

Edit:
To make the above working you should define your own 'clone' method, because default clone is 'shallow' and use references as well, hence not helping in this issue.

Comment: It didn't make any change doing that. 
About the note, I know that, however, the matrix that goes in the first if are the correct ones that I would like to store. 
Also if I print the solutions in the ArrayList inside that conditional if, it prints correctly all the solutions. But when I try to use outside this function I just get a full false matrix

Comment: Let's start from the reason you get a full false matrix:  for each x,y, after all the recursive calls, you set visited[x][y] to be false. hence you have an invariant that the finite state of each cell is false. and thats the reason you cant use it outside the function

Comment: And about fixing the issue itself, perhaps you need to make your own clone method.
A clone that copies the values themselves. are you comfortable with that?

Comment: I agree with you, however I just add a matrix to the solution ArrayList if it reach a specific point (x,y), so it's not adding a false matrix to the solution ArrayList. What I believe is happening, is that the changes I do inside that function does not have any effect on the solution attribute itself. And when the recursive calls ends, I end up losing the solution ArrayList

Comment: about making a own clone method I never made it, but I suppose I can handle it

Comment: The point is that you always add the 'same' matrix to the list.
'same': because the values are different each call, but the identity of the matrix is same.
just for interest, if you print in the condition (where you get successful prints) the *whole* arraylist, do you get what you would expect?

Comment: Yes, all the solutions I wanted are printed inside that condition